# Detect Mouse Wheel on a button

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following control hierarchy

```
    Form
        TabControl
            Panel
                Button
```

I'm trying to detect mouse wheel event over the button. I understand that for mouse-wheel event to be captured by the control it has to be in focus, while my button is currently not in focus?

I first attached the wheel event to the panel and then to the button however in both cases it wouldn't detect the event, probably due to the fact that it wasn't in focus.

Now I have attached the even on to the form, and the form detects the wheel event

```
this.MouseWheel +=Form1_MouseWheel;
```

I then try to detect the child under the mouse using the following code

```
private void Form1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Delta > 0) {
            Debug.WriteLine("SCROLL UP..." + e.Delta);
        } else {
            Debug.WriteLine("SCROLL DOWN..." + e.Delta);
        }

        Control ctrl = this.GetChildAtPoint(e.Location);

        if (ctrl != null) {
            Debug.WriteLine("Wheeling Over " + ctrl.Name);
        }
}
```

However the code only prints `tabControl1`.

Is there a method to get children deeper down the hierarchy, and get the correct `Control` that is currently under the mouse while mouse wheel is active?

Answer (score 4):

A Button needs to be the Active Control to raise `MouseWheel` events.
[Control.GetChildAtPoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.getchildatpoint) returns the direct child of the Control from which the method is called that contains the Mouse position (this may also depend on the System version in use).

If you can PInvoke, you can use [WindowFromPoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-windowfrompoint) to detect the Control that is currently under the Mouse pointer position.
Take into account the notes you can find in the Docs:

> The return value is a handle to the window that contains the point. If no window exists at the given point, the return value is NULL. If
> the point is over a static text control, the return value is a handle
> to the window under the static text control.

▲ Doesn't apply to WinForms Labels, these do return a Handle.

Note:
**`WindowFromPoint`** doesn't return the Handle of **all** Controls:

- The function doesn't return the Handle of Controls that are not visible or disabled.
- If a control that can scroll (TextBoxes, RichTextBoxes) has the capture (the Control is active and contains the caret), you won't receive MouseWheel events, since these events are received by the Control, not the Form.
- Some Controls cannot return a handle: the TextBox of a ComboBox with `DropDownStyle = DropDown` and the ToolStripProgressBar (for example).

You may also want to take a look at [ChildWindowFromPointEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-childwindowfrompointex) and [RealChildWindowFromPoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-realchildwindowfrompoint).

---

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
internal static extern IntPtr WindowFromPoint(Point point);

internal const int WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200;
internal const int WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A;
internal const int WM_MOUSEHWHEEL = 0x020E;
internal const int WM_MOUSEHOVER = 0x02A1
```

Override `WndProc` of your Form and get the Control under the Mouse Pointer with [Control.FromFandle()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.fromhandle), using the Handle `WindowFromPoint` returned.
The current screen position of the Mouse pointer is returned by either [MousePosition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.mouseposition) or [Cursor.Position](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.cursor.position) (both return the same value in relation to the position).

I'm also adding [`WM_MOUSEHWHEEL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-mousehwheel), plus `WM_MOUSEMOVE` and `WM_MOUSEHOVER`, commented out: you may need them.

```
[SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    base.WndProc(ref m);

    switch (m.Msg) {
        case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
        case WM_MOUSEHWHEEL:
            Point pos = MousePosition;
            Console.WriteLine($"Position: {pos}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Delta: {(short)(m.WParam.ToInt32() >> 16)}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Mouse Button: {(short)m.WParam.ToInt32()}");

            IntPtr hWnd = WindowFromPoint(pos);
            if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero) {
                var control = Control.FromHandle(hWnd);
                Console.WriteLine($"Handle: {hWnd}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Control Name: " + control?.Name);
            }
            m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
            break;
        //case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        //    //Console.WriteLine($"{Control.ModifierKeys}");
        //    m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
        //    break;
        //case WM_MOUSEHOVER:
        //    //Console.WriteLine($"{Control.ModifierKeys}");
        //    m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
        //    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you make sure to attach a MouseEventHandler to the button? I tried the following code and it worked as expected. (This code includes a Form > TabControl > Panel > Button as described.)

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button1.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(Button1_MouseWheel);
    }

    public void Button1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("ButtonWheel");
        MessageBox.Show("ButtonWheel");
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of form layout]

Comment: yes I had attached the event on the button, the mouse wheel event. And it didn't work, I thought it was related to the focus at that time, now I have changed the my code to wheel event on the main form. It's interesting to though  that you got it to work even without the button in focus.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? I tried this on 4.7.2.

Comment: I have set it to Net 4.0 in VS

Comment: Hmm. Could I possibly trouble you to try reconstructing the small example I put together and see what happens? I’m curious myself to figure out what’s causing it to work in this example and not in your production code.

Comment: I will try it later in the day, currently i do have some deadlines to meet.